# How to transfer data from views-view-fields.tpl to views-view-unformatted.tpl in D7?

Tags: 7, theming, views

I need to collect some data within views-view-fields.tpl, and then transfer it to  views-view-unformatted.tpl to do some magic to the whole data-object. How could I do that? Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now put the following code into my template.php

```
$_SESSION['myVar'] = array();
```

but I don't know if this is the best solution...

Answer (score 1):

You should use $view->result variable.

do dsm($view->result) and see if you find what you where looking for.

Comment: thanx! but I need to use an object build in the fields-tpl inside the unformatted-tpl.